# Stata duplicates drop with case insensitivity

Tags: stata

I've always used this

```
duplicates drop
```

to take care of duplicates.

However, this command thinks "Apple Computer" and "apple computer" are different. But obviously, they are the same. How can I remove such duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so. The strings are different to a programmer because they are not equal, and `duplicates` is entitled, indeed instructed, to treat them differently.

It's your decision to regard difference of upper case and lower case as immaterial. So, this example would be fixed by comparing strings made all upper case or all lower case using `upper()` or `lower()`.

Further, the help for `duplicates` explains:

> Duplicates are observations with identical values either on all
> variables if no *varlist* is specified or on a specified *varlist*.

so for `duplicates drop` to drop observations values would need to be identical on all variables.